# IF / CASE statement in Where in Oracle (OR)

Tags: oracle, where-clause

I want to search for a rows between two dates. In each row there is a column with date. I want to decrease this date by 1 and always display the results with that column decreased by 1 day.

For example - I'm searching between **2021-07-08 00:00:00** and **2021-07-08 23:59:59** so I want to search for columns with date **2021-07-09** but display them as **2021-07-08**.

The problem is that I want to exclude from that searching holidays and weekend. So for example if I will search between **2021-07-09 00:00:00** and **2021-07-09 23:59:59** then I want to search for columns with with date **2021-07-12** and display them as **2021-07-09**.

For holidays I have a list:

```
    with BANKHOLIDAYSUK as(
select COLUMN_VALUE as HOLIDAYDATE
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list  (
TO_DATE('30/08/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('27/12/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('28/12/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('01/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('03/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('15/04/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('18/04/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('02/05/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('02/06/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('03/06/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('29/08/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('26/12/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('27/12/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('01/01/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('02/01/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('07/04/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('10/04/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('01/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('29/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('28/08/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('25/12/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('26/12/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
,TO_DATE('09/07/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')))
)
```

How to check in where clause that we have **:start** or **:end** date into that list or weekend.

I've tried with:

```
where 
to_date(to_char(from_tz( cast( (o.DUEDATEUTC - 1)  as timestamp ), 'UTC' ) at time zone to_char(l.oracletimezone  ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') between :startDate and :endDate
OR (
(SELECT * FROM BANKHOLIDAYSUK WHERE HOLIDAYDATE = TO_DATE(:startdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) is not null 
and to_date(to_char(from_tz( cast( (o.DUEDATEUTC - 1)  as timestamp ), 'UTC' ) at time zone to_char(l.oracletimezone  ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') between :startDate and :endDate
)
  OR

(
((SELECT to_char(:startDate, 'd') FROM DUAL) = 5)
and to_date(to_char(from_tz( cast( (o.DUEDATEUTC - 3)  as timestamp ), 'UTC' ) at time zone to_char(l.oracletimezone  ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') between :startDate and :endDate
)
```

But it seems like executing of the query goes forever...

l.oracletimezone is an column with timezone for different locations.

Of course I'm using decreasing also in select.

Without OR statements it works but as I said only between monday and thursday. If we select between friday date then we will get nothing cause there is no 'DUEDATE' until weekend days.

Is my logic is wrong here?

Example:

| id | name | duedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electricity bill | 2021-07-08 |
| 2 | Water bill | 2021-07-09 |
| 3 | Rent bill | 2021-07-12 |

---

Search between **2021-07-07 00:00:00** and **2021-07-07 23:59:59**

Result:

| id | name | duedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electricity bill | 2021-07-07 |

---

Search between **2021-07-08 00:00:00** and **2021-07-08 23:59:59**

Result:

| id | name | duedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Water bill | 2021-07-08 |

---

Search between **2021-07-09 00:00:00** and **2021-07-09 23:59:59**

Result:

| id | name | duedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rent bill | 2021-07-09 |

---

Search between **2021-07-07 00:00:00** and **2021-07-09 23:59:59**

Result:

| id | name | duedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electricity bill | 2021-07-07 |
| 2 | Water bill | 2021-07-08 |
| 3 | Rent bill | 2021-07-09 |

Comment: `The problem is that I want to exclude from that searching holidays and weekend. So for example if I will search between 2021-07-09 00:00:00 and 2021-07-09 23:59:59 then I want to search for columns with with date 2021-07-12 and display them as 2021-07-12.` --- are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, cause I'm checking what I need to do on friday and its having due date to monday.

// Edit - I'm sorry I want to display it as 2021-07-09

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for **ALL** your (relevant) tables; DML (`INSERT`) statements for all those tables; and your expected output (if necessary, several expected outputs for inputs of different days). Trying to read through your logic and your code is very difficult and a complete worked example would probably help to make things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION next_working_day(
  day IN DATE
) RETURN DATE
IS
  working_day DATE;
BEGIN
  working_day := day + CASE TRUNC(day) - TRUNC(day, 'IW')
                       WHEN 5 THEN 2 -- Saturday
                       WHEN 6 THEN 1 -- Sunday
                       ELSE 0        -- Weekday
                       END;
  
  WITH non_holiday_date ( day, skip ) AS (
    SELECT working_day,
           NVL2(
             b.holidaydate,
             CASE TRUNC(working_day) - TRUNC(working_day, 'IW')
             WHEN 4 THEN 3 -- Friday
             ELSE 1        -- Any other weekday
             END,
             0
           )
    FROM   DUAL d
           LEFT OUTER JOIN bankholidaysuk b
           ON (TRUNC(working_day) = b.holidaydate)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT day + skip,
           NVL2(
             b.holidaydate,
             CASE TRUNC(day) - TRUNC(day, 'IW')
             WHEN 4 THEN 3 -- Friday
             ELSE 1        -- Any other weekday
             END,
             0
           )
    FROM   non_holiday_date n
           LEFT OUTER JOIN bankholidaysuk b
           ON (TRUNC(day) + skip = b.holidaydate)
    WHERE  n.skip > 0
  )
  SELECT day
  INTO   working_day
  FROM   non_holiday_date
  WHERE  skip = 0;
  
  RETURN working_day;
END;
/
```

Then, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (id, name, duedateutc) AS
SELECT 1, 'Electricity bill', DATE '2021-08-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Water bill',       DATE '2021-08-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Rent bill',        DATE '2021-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'XYZ bill',         DATE '2021-12-29' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE BANKHOLIDAYSUK ( holidaydate ) as
SELECT DATE '2021-08-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-28' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table o
WHERE  o.duedateutc BETWEEN next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-19' + 1 )
                    AND     next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-19' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND + 1 )
```

Gets the bill due on the next day and outputs:

> | ID | NAME | DUEDATEUTC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Electricity bill | 2021-08-20 00:00:00 |

and:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table o
WHERE  o.duedateutc BETWEEN next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-20' + 1 )
                    AND     next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-20' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND + 1 )
```

Skips the weekend and gets the bill on the next Monday and outputs:

> | ID | NAME | DUEDATEUTC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | Water bill | 2021-08-23 00:00:00 |

and:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table o
WHERE  o.duedateutc BETWEEN next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-27' + 1 )
                    AND     next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-27' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND + 1 )
```

Skips the weekend and the Monday holiday and gets the bill on the next Tuesday and outputs:

> | ID | NAME | DUEDATEUTC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | Rent bill | 2021-08-31 00:00:00 |

and:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table o
WHERE  o.duedateutc BETWEEN next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-19' + 1 )
                    AND     next_working_day( DATE '2021-08-27' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND + 1 )
```

Gets all the previous bills, outputting:

> | ID | NAME | DUEDATEUTC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Electricity bill | 2021-08-20 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | Water bill | 2021-08-23 00:00:00 |
> | 3 | Rent bill | 2021-08-31 00:00:00 |

and:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table o
WHERE  o.duedateutc BETWEEN next_working_day( DATE '2021-12-24' + 1 )
                    AND     next_working_day( DATE '2021-12-24' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND + 1 )
```

Skips the weekend and the 2-day Christmas holiday and gets the bill on the next Wednesday, outputting:

> | ID | NAME | DUEDATEUTC |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | XYZ bill | 2021-12-29 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=160435e8e815e50a73fc57f02c05d7c5)*

Comment: I didn't expect such a expanded answer!

Sorry for long time to answer - I had medical break from job...

Thank you, it's working as expected! : )